React Native: Axios Network Error on API Call in Android Emulator
I have an existing React Native project that was running fine in the Android Studio emulator. However, when it comes to submitting a form, the API call is not being made, and I am getting an Axios network error.
I have tried using the fetch function, but it is still not working for me.
How can I successfully hit the API and see the API status in the network? Are there any specific configurations or settings I need to check or adjust?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is basically impossible for us to answer without more details. But you can see in the axios network error response what the error is by loggin error.response.data.error

I suggest you install Flipper or try to debug the network using "Inspector" in your app.
